# Why doesn't Apache serve PHP files with a Last-Modified header?

Tags: php, apache, http-headers

Is this by design?

On my Debian (Etch) server I noticed that Apache (2.2) will not send a `Last-Modified` header when serving PHP (mod_5.2.0) files (we're talking plain-jane `echo 'Hello World';` PHP files).

Additionally, I noticed that the header `Accept-Ranges` is also not served by Apache for PHP files, although my main conern for the moment is the `Last-Modified` header.

Comment: You are supposed to set those headers explicitly inside PHP.

Comment: Apache has no way of telling whether your php file is *plain-jane* `echo 'Hello World';` or not. `echo date("Y-m-d");` is exactly the same size but serves different content every day.

Comment: It makes perfect sense, thank you! I still wonder about the Accept-Ranges header, though. From my understanding, it's simply used for download resuming purposes. Is the Accept-Ranges header removed because it doesn't want the client to resume downloading dynamic content?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP are dynamic page that can change. So Apache can't know the Last-Modified header.

You can add your own header with:

```
 header('Last-Modified: GMT time');
```

Of course if you need this header maybe you are looking to manage the request header If-Modified-Since too.

You can find it in `$_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']`

Answer (score 0):

it only sends this with static files. php files aren't static.

but you can send them yourself, see http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getlastmod.php#30514 for an example.